# Can't Get Code First Automatic Migration to Work On Existing SQL Server CE Database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

**Summary:**

I'll start with the summary and then follow with the details. For my project, automatic migration is not happening on the live .sdf database file in the working directory.  It's as if that .sdf file didn't exist.  Instead, all configuration actions are performed on a new, empty database file which it creates on in the `Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE` directory.  How do I get it to work on my live .sdf database file in the working directory?

**Details:**

The project uses Code First EF in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.  The project was started with EF 4.1, and I just updated the project to EF 4.4.

The database file is a SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 file, which is located in the same directory as the executable (i.e., the working directory).  Everything has been working fine for some time now, but I want to add two new DbSets to the DbContext, and hence two new tables to the database file.  When I deploy the new version of the program to customers, I want the program to seamlessly just add the two new tables to the database, and continue on as if nothing had happened, leaving untouched all the extant data in the other tables.

**Attempt 1**

Per the process described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj554735:

I added to two new DbSets to the DbContext-derived class.  When I attempted to run the program, I got the following exception:  `The model backing the 'DrillContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database`.  This is what I expected to happen, since I hadn't yet enabled migrations.

In the Package Management Console I then issued the command:

```
Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations.
```

The system created a `Migrations` directory with a `Configuration.cs` file in it.

I then ran the

```
Update-Database
```

command, and got the message `No pending code-based migrations`.  I checked the live database file in the working directory, and it was unchanged.  There was, however, a new database file with the same name in the `Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE` directory that had the same name and was an empty database with all the appropriate tables, including the two tables corresponding to the two new DbSets in the DbContext-derived class, and a new table named `_MigrationHistory`, which has a single entry in it.  The live .sdf file remained untouched, without the new tables, and with no `_MigrationHistory` table.

**Attempt 2, which uses an "InitialMigration":**

Per http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2012/03/ef-4-3-migrations-and-existing-database/

To prepare for the second attempt I restored the program's original state (i.e., to the state it was before I attempted the migrations) by doing 3 things.  I removed the 2 new DbSets from the DbContext-derived class.  I deleted the Migrations directory (and the enclosed Configuration.cs file), and deleted the useless database file (.sdf file) in the ".../Common7/IDE" directory.

I then executed the command:

```
Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations
```

which created the Migrations directory and the Configurations.cs file.

I then executed the

```
Add-Migration InitialMigration -IgnoreChanges
```

command, which added an `201208281905525_InitialMigration.cs` file to the Migrations directory.

Then, per the directions on the cited web page, I modified the `Up` method in the file so that the `InitialMigration` class became the following:

```
public partial class InitialMigration : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql("DROP TABLE EdmMetadata");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

I then executed the

```
Update-Database
```

command, and got the message `The specified table does not exist.`  I checked the live database in the working directory, and found that there is indeed an EdmMetadata table in the database.  I then checked the `.../Common7/IDE` directory and found that the new database that had been created there did NOT have the table.

So all "migration" activity is occurring on the `.../Common7/IDE` version of the file but not on the live database file in the working directory.

How do I get it to work on the existing, live database file?

Thanks,

Comment: Hello?!!  Is anyone from the Microsoft EF team out there?  Hello??  Anyone know the answer?

Comment: Please, check you connection string. Can you provide DbContext class code?

Comment: Could you please show us the `DbContext` class or the config file where the connection to database is declared?

Comment: I had a lot of problems myself with Migrations. It works differently in the local environment and differently in the host. Once the tables go out of synch... you need to REALLY know what is happening. I solved my problem using a tool from Red Gate called "SQL COMPARE." It's really cool and intuitive. It will allow you to create your table and match them to local or to host - your choice. Please go and see my answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084105/3777098 Rather than relying on migrations, change to a better tool - its free for 2 weeks so you can at least get yourself out of this par