# Getting EF Context has Changed Error After Updating Site

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am having an issue where I am getting an error "context has changed since the database was created," but when I look at the migrations history table it is the latest migration.  This is a test site, so I updated the database using a sql script I got by running this command "Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase"  I can't just delete the whole database and recreate it.  Has anyone run into a similar issue like this?  Currently, I am using EF 6.1.3.

Note: I used code-first for this, so it was not an existing database I am adding to.

Comment: Go see my answer here. This will definitely help you. The folks in REDGATE have a great tool for this problem. I wish Microsoft would create one too. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28084105/3777098

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that a new directory had been created for the site due to the domain name being changed.  I knew the domain name had changed, but didn't realize the physical directory had changes.  It was such a slight change I missed it when I was checking the application paths (an s was removed).  So the problem was caused by pebkac (problem exists between keyboard and chair).

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your Initializer to null in the constructor of your DbContext class.

Like this:

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContext>(null);
```

ScottGu's Blog explains why this happens :

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database

Comment: I created this database using code-first, so I don't believe ScottGu's article is related to this.  As far as I can tell, both the code and database should be using the same migrations, but I get the error I mentioned above.  Something is out of sync, not sure what.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this command instead of executing a script?

Update-Database -Force

If you have enabled auto migrations, this should pick up your code-first changes and deploy them. The force will allow columns which have data to be dropped etc.

Comment: The sql server is on a server I don't have access from my dev machine (I am a subcontractor).  So I need to upload the files by ftp and then update the database with the sql script from rdp.