# DbMigrator trying to execute every migration, not detecting executed migrations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to create a service call that will update an EF code first database to the latest version. However, it is always trying (and failing obviously) to execute all migrations, whether they were executed already or not.

Here's my code:

```
        var config = new DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>();
        config.MigrationsAssembly = typeof (MyContext).Assembly;
        config.MigrationsNamespace = "Context.Migrations";

        //This had no effect
        //config.SetHistoryContextFactory(connectionString.ProviderName, (connection, s) => new HistoryContext(context.Database.Connection, "dbo"));
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(config);

        //This gets every single migration, even the ones already executed before
        var migrations = migrator.GetPendingMigrations();
        //This gets 0 migrations
        var existing = migrator.GetDatabaseMigrations();
        //This gets all migrations
        var other = migrator.GetLocalMigrations();

        //This returns true! So it knows all the migrations are already executed
        var differ = context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true);
        //This will throw an exception because it's trying to create existing tables!
        migrator.Update();
```

I can confirm that the migration history table contains [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] references all the old migrations.

I checked the connection strings in the migrator. I also tried setting the history context factory manually in case it is looking somewhere else with no result. Also, running update-database directly from the console works and says no pending updates.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure [DbMigrationsConfiguration.ContextKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration.ContextKey);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) is set correctly.

The default value after this line

```
var config = new DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>();
```

will be like this

```
"System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1[MyContextNamespace.MyContext]"
```

You need to add the following line

```
config.ContextKey = "{Your_Context_Key}";
```

If you don't know the context key, open your `[dbo].[__MigrationHistory]` table and look at the `ContextKey` column.

Once you set it up correctly, if your database is up-to-date, `migrator.GetPendingMigrations()` should return empty and `migrator.GetDatabaseMigrations()` should return all migrations.

Comment: This is it!  Your points will arrive in ~21 hours when I am allowed to approve them.

Comment: Tbh I had given up and changed my entire procedure. Thanks so much for this!

Answer (score -1):

If your database is all updated, and you have no need for the old migration tables, then what I would suggest that you do is delete the migrations folder and recreate it using

```
  enable-migrations
```

I do it all the time when the migrations mess up. I never need the historical migrations - once they have done their job - they are DONE! Be sure to save your seed method if you are seeing through the configuration. You can look at my earlier post on this, maybe that will help too.

[Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084105/3777098)

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - We are always setting up new instance of the same database, so deleting old migrations is not an option

Comment: Once you have amended the database, the new instance would be set up as the last shape when you enable migrations again. When enabling migrations, migrations gives you a script with the last final data shape, use that script to set up your new instances of the same database. It would be like running the final snapshot of all the historical old scripts. You would get your final database. Then start developing again and adding to it.

Comment: "If your database is all updated" : the asker's problem is that the database may not be updated.